# jQuery Validate plugin regex addMethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have an project that is using the jQuery Validate plugin where I like to add an alphanumericwithnospace regex method.

In the jQuery Validate methods I added my new method

```
 $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, elem, regexp) {
        if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
            regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        else if (regexp.global)
            regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    },
    "Only alphanumeric characters allowed");
```

Then in the aspx page I have the input object

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>
<span class="required">*
</span>
Code:
</label>
<input class="form-control glValidate"  name="txtCode" id="txtCode" />
</div>
```

In my form-Validate I also added the rules.

```
validate();
$('.glValidate').each(function () {
$("#txtCode").rules("add", {
regex:true,
})
$(this).rules('add', {
required: true,
});
});
```

so I am not sure what step I am missing in order for this object to be used. The error that i am getting is that the ReferenceError: regex is not defined